# Are private methods in Sencha Touch inherited?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Given:

```
// @private
updateInactiveLabel: function(newInactiveLabel, oldInactiveLabel) {
    if (newInactiveLabel != oldInactiveLabel) {
        this.getComponent().element.dom.setAttribute('data-inactivelabel', newInactiveLabel);
    }
},
```

*the above is a fragment code of Ext.field.Toggle*

**Will this method be inherited by a user defined class that extends Toggle   (MyToggle)?**

I mean is this `// @private` an annotation that prevents inheritance of the method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, private methods will be inherited unless they're overriden.

The `@private` notation is for documentation purposes.

Comment: Technically you shouldn't rely on a method's existence if marked as private - a later version of Sencha Touch might change or remove it.